# Permanent memory leak when using Directory.GetDirectories and Directory.EnumerateDirectories

Tags: c#, .net

I've encountered an extremely weird situation where running a very simple application causes memory to be permanently lost (until the system is rebooted).  Here is the code below:

```
List<string> list = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("G:\\Video", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
List<string> list2 = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("H:\\Video", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

This is all the code in the application.  In these video folders, there are more folders (about 30 or so) which contain hundreds of .avi video clips.  When this application is run, memory gradually decreases by about 10 MB every 30 seconds or so (so if I let it run for a couple hours, a GB or more of memory will be missing.)  Although in task manager, the memory doesn't show up under this application.  It actually shows no where.  When stopping this application, the memory ISN'T recovered.  It's like something on the computer is somehow seeing that the above code is being called and then loading the files from the above search into memory.  Any ideas on what could be doing this?  No other applications are running (in task manager) and visual studio isn't installed on the machine this is occuring.

Comment: This also does the same exact thing when using Directory.GetDirectories instead of Directory.EnumerateDirectories

Comment: Directory.EnumerateFiles also does the same thing (increased the memory which is permanently lost even when the process is stopped).

Comment: Could this be a memory leak by the CLR somehow?

Comment: Instead of guessing that it is your program that using the memory, why not [use a tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) to figure out what exactly is using the memory?

Comment: These functions are not the problem. Call them 1e9 times in a loop and observe that memory usage is not increasing. This is proof that your code leaks.

Comment: Is windows update running? I noticed similar behavior previously on my win8 pc, once the update was complete it went back to normal usage.

Comment: usr, the problem is that the code above is the only code in my application.  I created a blank windows form application and inserted those two lines.  After running both those routines, about 1.5 GB of RAM is lost to "nowhere" (and doesn't show up again until rebooting).  The lost memory doesn't show up in task manager or process monitor.  I'm now running .net Memory validator so will see what I get there...

Comment: I should add that each of those Video folders contains about 30 or so more folders which in total contain about 500,000 files (either .avi or .wav)

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in the directories and files search routines.  If running these routines over a folder with hundreds of thousands of files, then it takes a couple minutes to finish (slowly sucking up memory), but the memory isn't ever released (even when the application is exited).  What's also weird is that the subsequent times I run the code above it goes much much faster (seconds to complete instead of minutes).  It's like the CLR is caching something about these routines so that if they're called again it goes faster.

Comment: are you running in Visual Studio? What happens you run the exe out of the debugger? What version of the framework are you using? Does this happen in 4.5 or 2.0? What version of Windows are you running? Where are you calling the posted code (from the form or direct from `Main`)? I just tried this on my 50k+ video library and noticed no ill effects (i.e. my .NET application only used 24MB of memory and no memory was lost .. according to my `taskmanager`)

Comment: Rather than articulate what is not working did you try my answer?  The ToList() forces that to go to memory before it is evaluated so you lose the benefits of a EnumerateDirectories.

Comment: Not using visual studio.  No development tools are on the system, and this happens on multiple systems.  .net 4.0 is the version.  Windows 7 is the OS.  Txtechhelp, if you run that and look at available physical memory under the Performance tab in task manager, does it keep going down?  It DOES NOT go up for me in Processes view.  Watch it using the Performance tab.  It like the CLR is using up the memory for this routine but failing to release it.

Comment: Blam, it does the same thing with Directory.GetDirectories (and Directory.EnumerateFiles)

Comment: Txtechhelp, if you want to try to reproduce what I'm doing, do this:  reboot the system (since the memory from when you ran it the first time may already be lost, which means it might not be noticable in sub sequent runs).  Then after rebooting, run the app and watch the Performance tab in task manager

Comment: @Blam I figured out what was happening.  When Directory.GetDirectories is called over a folder with lots of large files, windows loads the file cache (which which by default set to around 1 GB so at times it would use that much RAM just because of walking a directory tree).  To get around this, the file cache max size needs to be changed.  This can be done through the wind32 api function SetSystemFileCacheSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grins would your try this

```
List<string> list = = new List<string>();
foreach(var v in  Directory.EnumerateDirectories("G:\\Video", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) list.add(v.ToString());
```

Comment: It di dthe same thing.  My available memory went from 6654 to 5708 (so a ~900 MB loss in memory) and when I exited the process, the memory was never returned.  So my memory usage is now at 2.24 GB (according to the task manager Performance view) which is almost a GB more than where it started before I ran the application.  I won't get the memory back now until I restart.

Comment: Do NOT be so sure you are not getting your memory back.  TaskManager is not a good way to measure memory usage.  Use a proper memory manager like Ants before you conclude you did not get memory back.

Comment: I checked it with RAMMap and the Memory statistic in the Performance view of task manager is correct.  There is definitely a bug here with the CLR since this lost memory (1.5 GB or so) is lost by running the above code on our folders (which contain over 500,000 files).  It happens every time and is 100% reproducible.  GetDirectories, GetFiles, EnumerateDirectories, and EnumerateFiles and cause this to happen.  I will have to report it.

Comment: Allocated and used are not the same.  I would validate with memory manger like Ants.  There is a difference between range of memory allocated and what is actually allocated within the range.   Other than the reports you see do you have evidence the memory is not available.  Lost and not reported as available it not the same.  Do you have explicit evidence (e.g. a program won't) that the memory is not available?  Put those two call in an open loop and if you get an OOM - then you have direct evidence.

Comment: Yes, this program is causing a lot of memory crashes (it pushes our systems to 3.98-3.99 GB usage on 4 GB systems, so then when someone does something on the system, applications start to crash).

Comment: I'm getting the results for Ants so will post back

Comment: Wow, then it does sound a bug.

Comment: So it's not a bug, but a feature inside windows for caching (File Cache).  These cache settings can only be changed through the win32 api (SetSystemFileCacheSize).